# How to join two tables and apply join condition only for non-null values in certain columns?

Tags: sql, hana

I have a requirement where I need to lookup information from Table 1 into Table 2.

Table 1 Has 7 Columns. Columns 1 is the lookup value. The remaining columns can or cannot contain a value.

Table 2 has the Sales Information and contains all the 7 Columns from T1.

The problem statement is as follows,

1. I need to lookup the Information in Columns 1 with a join between the tables.
2. The join Condition for a column (Remaining 6 in T1)  should be considered only if the Column has a value in T1.
3. If there is no Value for the column in T1, this condition should not influence the output. Meaning this Join Condition should not be active. I am not even sure this is possible

I have tried IF and CASE but no luck. I request the experts to help me with this requirement.

Thanks & Regards

Karthik

1. AND ((T1."SALES_OFFICE" IS NOT NULL) AND T2."SALES_OFFICE" = T1."SALES_OFFICE")

If Sales Office is null, it would not consider the row. Lime mentioned the other 5 Columns in T1 can have values which would make up the conditions.

2. AND T2."/BIC/ZZMVGR6" = ( CASE WHEN (T1."SALES_OFFICE" != '') THEN T1."SALES_OFFICE"
   ELSE 'Dont use this Rule' END )

I need a wa to not use this rule if the value in T1 does not exist

Comment: `T2."SALES_OFFICE" = T1."SALES_OFFICE` will only be true for non-null T1."SALES_OFFICE` values. I.e. no need for `T1."SALES_OFFICE" IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Thanks, but when it is Null this columns shouldnt be considered for the Join

Comment: I told you It isn't...

Comment: A [mcve] would make things much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You want to consider table1 columns in the join criteria only if these columns are set (i.e. not null). This should look like this:

```
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.col1 = t1.col1
               AND (t2.col2 = t1.col2 OR t1.col2 IS NULL)
               AND (t2.col3 = t1.col3 OR t1.col3 IS NULL)
               AND (t2.col4 = t1.col4 OR t1.col4 IS NULL)
               AND (t2.col5 = t1.col5 OR t1.col5 IS NULL)
               AND (t2.col6 = t1.col6 OR t1.col6 IS NULL)
               AND (t2.col7 = t1.col7 OR t1.col7 IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result from this query :

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.column1 = table2.column1
AND table1.column2 IS NOT NULL
AND table2.column2 IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Always explain what your queries do and how they solve the given problem.

Comment: The `IS NOT NULL` makes no difference here. `table1.column1 = table2.column1` will only be true for non-null values.